# React component not rerender on state change

Tags: forms, reactjs, state, render

I'm rendering the following form component **twice** in an other component. Problem is that when I enter a value in one of the rendered forms, it doesn't update the placeholder of the other form. How do I get react to re-render component after state change so that both forms have the same placeholder value?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o4h5af4g/7/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LengthForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      length:1
    };
  }

 handleChange(event) {
   this.setState({length: event.target.value});
 }

 render() {
    return (
      <div className="LenghtForm">
        <input name="length" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} type="integer" placeholder={this.state.length}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LengthForm;
```

Comment: you need use Redux....

Answer (score 2):

I think you just missed to initialize the input (input's value property) with the value from your state. This should trigger the re-render

```
<input name="length" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
   type="integer" placeholder={this.state.length}
   value={this.state.length} />
```

Another flaw in your code is the constructor. You should set props first thing.

```
constructor(props){ 
   super(props); 
   this.state = { length: 1 }; 
}
```

Comment: Tried it. No change.

Comment: Another problem in your code is the constructor. You should set props first thing. `constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      length:1
    };
  }`

Comment: They are in my code, but I forgot them when writing the example.

Comment: Could we see your actual code? Otherwise it's hard to help you

Comment: I will try to set up a fiddle.

Comment: Ok, you have two instances of your component. And no common parent. They are isolated. If you want to have a single state that manages both, you need a common parent or use a sophisticated state management (like Redux).

Comment: Okay got it fixed! I added a length prop to the elements in the parent component and changed input to have placeholder={this.props.length}.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Comment: My pleasure Sir